# How to use RegEx in sscanf() to tokenize a string a specific way in c?

Tags: c, regex, tokenize, scanf

I want to break this following text in string:

```
John, Smith, 10 Maple Street, Cullowhee, NC, 28779, 828.123.4567
   Susan, thompson, 21 Oak Road, Webster, NC, 28711, 828.434.3232
Sarah, foster, 32 Sycamore Street, Sylva, NC, 28712, 828.112.3456
bruce, Hampton, 321 Linden Street, Dillsboro, NC, 28123, 828.432.7895
   Bill, Thompson, 141 Cedar Drive, Sauk City, WI, 43214, 415.323.2254
```

This is what I have so far:

```
void sort(FILE* in, FILE* out){

char buffer[LINE_LENGTH];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL) {
    sscanf(buffer , "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],"
            "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", 
            str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7);
    i++;
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of the spaces/tabs present infront of the `Susan` and `Bill`. I am not sure what changes I need to make to `sscanf(buffer , **"%[^,]**` this first regex to remove those spaces. I have tried `[^a-zA-Z]` infront of the first `%[^,]`, tried replacing `%[^,]` with `%[^ ,] , %[^' ',], %[^' \t',]`. The change either does nothing or makes all strings disappear and only `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` comes up on console.

Comment: A space (or other white-space character) in a `scanf` format string tells `scanf` to skip white-space, so you could place a space before each `%[` format.

Comment: You cannot use regular expression in `sscanf()`. What is "RegEx"?

Comment: Thanks @ M Oehm and @user3121023.

Comment: @MikeCAT - RegEx - Regular Expression. Was it that hard to understand? And I just used this -> '%[^,]' in 'sscanf'. Is it not a string defined by a regular expression?

Comment: 'Was it that hard to understand?'  Yes, it was, because you cannot use regular expressions in sscanf().  sscanf does not support regular expressions.  sscanf does not handle regular expressions.  Regular expressions are badly handled by sscanf. The format string in the scanf() family is not a full-fledged regular expression.  Do you need it clearer than that?

Comment: @MartinJames don't get all worked up man. All I was saying was "RegEx means Regular Expression." Was that short form that hard to understand? And by the way, this is kinda controversial "sscanf does not handle regular expressions. Regular expressions are badly handled by sscanf."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A whitespace character in the format string of `*scanf` instructs `*scanf` to read and discard any number of whitespace characters, if any, until the first non-whitespace character.

This can be seen in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.

So just add a space before all the `%[` so that leading whitespace characters gets trimmed off.

---

Note: The last `%[^,]` needs to be changed to `%[^\n]` as there aren't any commas after it on that line.

Comment: Wow I can't believe this. All I was missing was a space before the first %[. I had spaces before the rest of the %[ already. Thanks a lot for pointing out this silliest thing ever.